# cant access desired data angularfire

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I´m making an android game who first lets users login, i figured out that part. the script makes an save of the userdata based on userID to user on later gameplay.

now i cant seem to figure out how to access the (level) data again (i would like to be able to scope it)

```
app.factory("Auth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var FIREB = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(FIREB);
});

app.controller('HomeScreen', function($scope,  Auth, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
        $scope.authData = authData;
    });
    var users = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/users/");
    // create a synchronized array
    $scope.users = $firebaseArray(users);
    $scope.googlelogin = function() {

        Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData){

            users.child($scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id).set({
                Username: $scope.authData.google.displayName,
                Id: $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id,
                Gender: $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.gender,
                level: "1"
            });
        }).catch(function(error){

        });
    }
    $scope.googlelogout = function() {
        Auth.$unauth();
    }

    $scope.changeLVL = function(authData, Auth) {
        var user = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/users/" + $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id);
        $scope.user = $firebaseArray(user);
        $scope.level = $firebaseObject(user.child("level"));
        var level = $firebaseObject(user.child("level"));

        user.update({
            level: level
        });

     }


});
```

Is there any way to easily target the level property ? currenly i was only able to show it as an array instead of an value. (example: shows "[]" instead of "2"  or shows the whole array {"level": "2"})

my firebase array is setup like this, where the number is the account id.

```
 users
   998995300163718
     Email: "Name@email.com"
     Gender: "male"
     Id:  "998995300163718"
     Username: "name lastname" 
     level: "1"
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do. Can you create an example on JSBin or Plunkr?

Comment: @DavidEast i try to get the level propert in a scope so i can use it like "$scope.level" or like {{ level }} problem is i need to target it for the specific logged in user.. and i cant seem to get the ref for that right

Comment: I think the last question I answered for you should help with that. If you can get the user resolved into the controller it will be a lot easier to target a specific user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983526/angularfire-cannot-read-property-facebook-how-do-i-keep-using-authdata-through

Comment: @DavidEast i wil take a closer look to it tomorrow... could it be that my firebase.add is messing up the auth process? Already much thanks btw

Comment: @DavidEast i did exactly what you did but it doesnt seem to work. any more advice?

Comment: That should work so can you recreate your problem in a JSBin or Plunkr?

Comment: @DavidEast after some work its running in plunkr. i figured out why the route was not working myself (piece of firebase code in the next controller) but i still cant seem to target the user specific level... and on a sidenote, i also cant seem to make it only create an new user when it doesn't exists (but thats a next problem) its like this in plunkr now http://plnkr.co/edit/WJOKQvwQ9NOQjscxJsFs?p=preview